# Large Icon in firebase notification

Tags: android, ios, cordova, firebase, firebase-notifications

I want to send large icon (may be any external URL) in notification from from firebase console or firebase Rest API to my Cordova application. So when user expands notification he has to see that notification .

I tested by sending values(key - image,value - url) in advanced data option in firebase console but still no use.

NOTE : When app is background I want this functionality .

Comment: Please some comment while doing negative vote

Answer (score 0):

I have only been able to do this from the rest API.

There is two notification types that can be sent.

One is normal notification with a data payload
this is the one you can send from the firebase conosle and will be automatically handled if the app is in the background therefore you cannot do what you want.

The other one is a Data notification
This is where you send it to the api but only send the data package and not the notification part.

When you send the data notification it will be handled as described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

you can then inside the handler create your notification and apply a big icon with a url that you send as a data value and display it to the user.

only drawback is that you will loose the schedule and tracking functionality provided by the firebase console